# Is it possible to use Talend installer for upgrading server applications?

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

When upgrading Talend server components such as TAC, Command Line, Job Server etc... Is it possible to use the talend installer instead of upgrading each application individually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the `Talend Installer` instead of installing each piece individually but here is the catch

1. `Talend` does not support in place upgrades, so for example even going from `Talend 6.2.1` to `Talend 6.3.1` requires a fresh new install- and they recommend doing it on brand new servers as you don't want to install multiple versions on same box.
2. If your deployment strategy utilizes multiple servers you will still be running the installer multiple times (e.g. `TAC` on separate server than your job server).

Comment: I have just one server which has 6.2. I'm thinking of using the installer to install 6.3 and migrate the old database to 6.3 and uninstall 6.2. Is it possible to migrate mdm database and data quality database the same way?